# Did Maupassant adapt the style and content of his stories to the newspapers that published them?

Tags: french-language, style, cultural-context, guy-de-maupassant

Guy de Maupassant published his short stories and novellas in newspapers and periodicals such as [*Le Figaro*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Figaro), [*Gil Blas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Blas_(periodical)), [*Le Gaulois*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Gaulois) and [*L'Écho de Paris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C3%89cho_de_Paris) before they were published in book form. *Le Figaro* has always been known as rather conservative (right to centre-right on the political spectrum); *Gil Blas* seems to have provided entertainment for a wide readership (and published works by many well-known authors such as Jules Barbey d'Aurevilly, Hector Malot, Octave Mirbeau, Jules Renard, Jules Vallès, Villiers de L'Isle-Adam and Émile Zola); *Le Gaulois* was well-informed and conservative, and had many readers among the nobility and the rich bourgeosie; *L'Écho de Paris* was initially conservative and patriotic but later became close to the French Social Party.

Assuming that these newspapers had different readerships with different tastes and moral orientations, did Maupassant adapt the stories he published in them to those different readerships? What I am looking for are differences in both style and content.